# C# foreach only get distinct values

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange)
{
    string driverid = log.did;
}
```

How would I only add distinct driver ID's to the driverid string?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't adding anything right now, it's just setting a string (declared in the scope of the loop) to each value. The end result would be only the last value, and it would be out of scope to the following code anyway. If you're trying to append them all to a string, separated by commas, e.g., try this:

```
string driverids = string.Join(",", _logsDutyStatusChange
  .Select(item=>item.did)
  .Distinct()
  .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 13):

You should do:

```
foreach (string id in _logsDutyStatusChange.Select(x=>x.did).Distinct())
{
    string driverid = id;
}
```

Comment: Might as well use `Last` after the `Distinct` and forgo the `foreach`

Comment: @juharr: I think it's reasonable to assume there's really more code than just a variable declaration within the loop body.

Comment: Well, I was not sure if he is doing something else with the id in the loop, as I understand this is just a sample he posted.

Answer (score 7):

mhh ... maybe use `IEnumerable< T >`'s `Distinct()` function?

Comment: +1, but an example would be useful if the OP doesn't know Linq ;)

Comment: well ... it seems that there are some examples on this page ;)

Answer (score 3):

This should work (without linq):

```
Hashset<string> alreadyEncountered = new Hashset<string>();
foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange)
{
    if(alreadyEncountered.Contains(log.did))
    {
        continue;
    }
    string driverid = log.did;
    alreadyEncountered.Add(driverid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create a comparer class and implement the `IEqualityComparer<Log>` interface:

```
public class LogComparer : IEqualityComparer<Log>
{
    public bool Equals(Log one, Log two)
    {
        return one.did.Equals(two.did);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Log log)
    { 
        return log.did.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then use the overload of the `Enumerable.Distinct()` method that takes an instance of the equality comparer:

```
foreach(var log in _logsDutyStatusChange.Distinct(new LogComparer()))
{
    // Work with each distinct log here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of foreach'ing _logsDutyStatusChange, you could use LINQ to get a collection of distinct and loop through those, instead:

```
foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange.Select(l => l.did).Distinct())
{
    //Handling code here
}
```

Implementation will depend exactly on what you intend to do with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Distinct if your Logs class implements IEquatable

Otherwise, a quick 'hacky' fix can be to use something like

```
foreach (var group in _logsDutyStatusChange.GroupBy(l => new { log.did, .... more identifying fields })
{
    string driverid = group.Key.did;
}
```

C# 4.0 tuples have 'automagic' comparing/equating as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
HashSet<string> SeenIDs = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange)
{
    if (SeenIDs.Contains(log.did)) break;
    SeenIDs.Add(log.did);

    string driverid = log.did;
}
```

`Distinct()` doesn't quite work here, as it will only get you the distinct `did`s.