# How can I show just distinct names (from my model) in my view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

### Problem

How can I return back just the distinct names in my view? I can't cast the string returned by my distinct() method back to an Inumerable object.

*For simplification, if you see a person named John Smith in the database, we assume all quotes from John Smith are from the same person.*

### Code

**Data**

```
id                name          quote
1                 Finn          Mathematical
2                 Jake          Aw, man! 
3                 Shredder      Tonight, I dine on turtle soup. 
4                 Shredder      Nooooo
```

**Model**

```
    namespace Quotes_Sample.Models
{
    public class QuoteDB
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string quote { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    }


    public class QuoteDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<QuoteDB> Quotes { get; set; }
    }


}
```

**Controller**

```
 private QuoteDBContext db = new QuoteDBContext();

    // GET: Quotes
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Quotes.ToList());
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Quotes_Sample.Models.QuoteDB>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitSelected", "Quotes", FormMethod.Post, new { encType = "multipart/form-data", name="myform"}))
    {

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Quotes_Sample.Models.QuoteDB>)Model.Select(x => x.name).Distinct())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>

    }

</body>
</html>
```

### Error

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_cied5w21.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>d__81`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Quotes_Sample.Models.QuoteDB]'.
```

### Attempts

- I can just remove the casting and have duplicates, but it's really
  ugly.
- I thought about writing a temp variable that remembers last
  name in loop, if same it breaks. That is just plain gross? Seems hacky too.
- Just having 1 name to 1 quote relationship in my database, but that avoids the problem completely.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704198/c-sharp-foreach-only-get-distinct-values), which actually brought me to this problem.
- This below:

  ```
  <table class="table">
      <tr>
          <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
          </th>
      </tr>
      @foreach (string name in Model.Select(x => x.name).Distinct())
      {
          <tr>
              <td>
                  @Html.DisplayText(name);
              </td>
          </tr>
      }
  </table>
  ```

  But that really weirds me out. It gives me the following:

  ```
  name 

  ;  
  ;  
  ;
  ```

Thanks for your patience and assistance.

Comment: Your issue is when you you call `Model.Select(x => x.name)`, the concept of the `QuoteDB` object is lost - you now have an `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: @Jonesy Right, I was investigating the error and you can see my attempt to fix it, but still getting bizarre output?

Comment: Also, if you achieve `IEnumerable<QuoteDB>` with distinct names, what quote value would you expect Shredder to have?  I think you're looking for `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `Distinct` records by name using:

```
Model.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(x => x.First())
```

But you should do this in your `Controller`, not `View`.

Also you can use [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method:

```
Model.DistinctBy(x => x.name)
```

Comment: This worked. Please, one more comment. Is the reason this logic belongs in the controller for two reasons. 1. Controller handles the data then passes to view by definition. 2. It would be sluggish and nasty to do it in a view.

Comment: the purpose of View is displaying the data, all other stuff (filtering, projecting etc.) should be done in Contoller.

Comment: Sanity check here. By model, you mean QuoteDBContext db, yes?

Comment: no it's the ViewModel but ofcourse you need  to use your DbContext if you are gonna do this in your controller